# How to configure Jenkins to run Selenium scripts on a Headless browser on Windows

Tags: selenium, jenkins

[image]I am trying to setup Jenkins to run my Selenium scripts on a Headless browser on Windows. I just found that xvfb only works for Unix based OS but not on Windows. Can anyone please help in configuring the same ?

I tried searching on Google but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Windows cannot run headless, so I do not know what it is you think you need to do. You do not need xvfb to run selenium with a headless browser, you need xvfb to run selenium with a headless running server.

Comment: Selenium tests when run via Jenkins it opens up the browser and runs the tests, I want my tests to be run in the background not opening any browser, how can I achieve this ?
Actually, I have installed Jenkins on my Windows (localhost) and want to run the tests without Jenkins opening the browser, so tried configuring xvfb which I learnt through Google that xvfb plugin needs to be installed and configured accordingly.

Comment: Edited my question with screenshot of the exact message on Jenkins's console output, please check the same

Comment: You are mistaken, xvfb is not what will make the test run headless. To run tests headless you need a headless browser. This means that you cannot use chrome, firefox, safari, internet explorer etc. Headless browsers include HTMLunit and phantomJS among others.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my previous project all scripts were written using Firefox driver but not using HTMLUnitDriver but still the jobs on Jenkins used to run without opening the browser. I want to run all my scripts written using FirefoxDriver headlessly on Jenkins. Can you please guide to how to achieve this ? Many thanks.

Comment: You can try running firefox in a virtual desktop, with something like this maybe: https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win but I have no experience with that.